# Bucles whiles anidados lanzan un error de MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

En el siguiente ceodigo tengo dos buclos While anidados, dentro de cada uno de ellos un query a MSSQL al ejecutarse el segundo PHP me lanza el siguiente error" "There was a problem connecting to SQL SERVER. SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: There are no more rows in teh active result set. Since this result set is not scrolleable no more data may be retrieved "

Estoy corriendoe l siguiente ceodigo en Windows server 2008 con php 7.0 y MSSQLSERVER 2014

```
  <?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$debug = false;

$serverName = "###"; //serverName\instanceName
$database = '###';
$user = '###';
$pass = '###';

$pagesize = 10; 
$offset = 0;

if($debug) {
    var_dump($response);  
} else {
    try {
        $pdo = new \PDO(
            sprintf(
                "sqlsrv:server=%s;Database=%s",
                $serverName,
                $database
            ),
            //$user, $pass  // depends on how we use the script
             NULL, NULL
        );
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        //query for a set of documents
        $dataset = 'SELECT itemdata.itemnum, itemdata.itemname, 
                    doctype.itemtypename, 
                    useraccount.username,
                    itemdatapage.filepath, itemdatapage.filesize,
                    itemdata.itemdate, itemdata.datestored, itemdata.itemtypenum as itemtypenum 
                    FROM hsi.itemdata as itemdata
                    LEFT JOIN hsi.useraccount ON itemdata.usernum = useraccount.usernum
                    LEFT JOIN hsi.itemdatapage ON itemdata.itemnum = itemdatapage.itemnum 
                    LEFT JOIN hsi.doctype ON itemdata.itemtypenum = doctype.itemtypenum
                    WHERE itemdatapage.itempagenum = 0
                    ORDER BY itemnum
                    OFFSET 90000 ROWS
                    FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;';

        $stmt = $pdo->query( $dataset );

        while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
            //search keywords table
            $selectTables = 'SELECT keytypenum
                            FROM [OnBase].[hsi].[itemtypexkeyword]
                            WHERE itemtypenum =' . $row['itemtypenum'];

                            $stmt = $pdo->query( $selectTables );

                            while ( $tables = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
                             print_r($tables);
                            }

        }




    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "There was a problem connecting to SQL SERVER. " . $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Intenta antes del segundo while asignarle $pdo->query a otra variable que no sea $stmt que es con la cual ejecutastes la primera consulta, algo como $stmt2 = $pdo->query($selectTables); recuerda que en tu segundo while debes llamar a esa misma variable nueva no a la vieja $stmt

Comment: Hay un error de lógica en tu programa. Aquí creas una sentencia: `$stmt = $pdo->query( $dataset );` a la cual le asignas la variable `$stmt`, y luego aquí creas otra sentencia: `$stmt = $pdo->query( $selectTables );` dentro del bucle. Pero el anterior `$stmt` está todavía trayendo datos. Lo correcto sería guardar los datos del primer statement en un array, cerrarlo y luego ejecutar el segundo. Aunque particularmente cuando veo consultas que se ejecutan dentro de bucles intuyo que algo está mal planteado, sea en tu diseño de datos, sea en la lógica que aplicas, pero ese es otro tema.

Comment: Por ejemplo, dado que en la tabla `itemtypexkeyword` hay una columna que se relaciona con el resultado de la primera consulta, ¿por qué no incluyes esa tabla que consultas dentro del bucle en un `JOIN` en la 1ª consulta? Lanzando una segunda consulta dentro del bucle estás usando demasiados recursos de forma innecesaria. Además, haciéndolo del otro modo y suponiendo que las tablas están bien indexadas, la diferencia de rendimiento será enorme, sobre todo si consultas muchos datos. Imagina que la consulta traiga 10,000 registros, ¡son 10,000 ejecuciones de consultas! cuando puedes hacer solo 1.

Comment: No la incluye en un JOIN porque la primer consulta me trae una sola fila por cada item en la tabla principal que es itemdata y volcando esa tabla tal cual está en otra nueva puedo tener migrados los datos que se relacionan uno a uno.

Comment: Debido a una caracteristica del programa que armo estas bases de datos yo debo saber por cáda item qué valores puedo encontrar en itemtypexkeyword. Allí voy a encontrar varios items repetidos y no necesito esos datos en mi conjunto de datos iniciales, solo los necesito saber para ver en que otras tablas debo hacer nuevas queries, es decir, aun precisaria mas anidamiento luego de este nivel. Estoy yendo por el camino de traer resultados, guardarlos en un array y destruir el objeto PDO y luego hacer nuevas consultas recorriendo el array antes guardado, con una nueva conexion a la DB.

Comment: Todo eso que comentas es muy raro. Si no normalizas los datos puede que en un momento determinado la aplicación comience a ser lenta, a consumir memoria, a crear datos inconsistentes. Para un proceso tan sencillo mira todas las vueltas que tienes que dar, como crezcan los requerimientos o los datos tendrás problemas serios tarde o temprano.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con vos, el problema es que yo no hice la aplicación solo estoy intentando migrar datos de una aplicación poco documentada que ya existe.

Comment: Tal como dicen el problema en ese caso era repetir la variable $stmt con el mismo nombre dos veces. Cambiando eso dejó de darme el error.